# Inquiry about number of adults in MIMIC-III v1.3

Tags: mimic-iii

I need to verify the number of adults I found in MIMIC III v1.3.

Based on the fact that age is defined by this formula:

```
((extract(DAY from admittime - dob) 
 + extract(HOUR from admittime - dob) / 24
 + extract(MINUTE from admittime - dob) / 24 / 60
  ) / 365.242)
```

and that adult is patients who are aged above 15 at the time of their first admission, there are 38,645 adults in the database among a total of 46,520 patients.

Could you please confirm or reject this number by giving the exact number of adults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query confirms that there are 46,520 distinct patients in MIMIC-III v1.3:

```
SELECT count(distinct subject_id)
FROM admissions;
-- returns 46520.
```

The following query confirms that the there are 38,645 distinct adult patients in MIMIC-III v1.3, based on the definition of 'adult' provided in the question:

```
WITH ages AS
(
    SELECT ad.subject_id, ad.hadm_id, ad.admittime, 
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ad.subject_id ORDER BY ad.admittime), 
               (extract(DAY FROM ad.admittime - p.dob) 
                + extract(HOUR FROM ad.admittime - p.dob) / 24
                + extract(MINUTE FROM ad.admittime - p.dob) / 24 / 60
                ) / 365.242 AS age
    FROM admissions ad
    INNER JOIN patients p
    ON ad.subject_id = p.subject_id 
)
SELECT count(distinct subject_id)
FROM ages
WHERE age > 15;
-- returns 38645
```